# Repeating loop inside another LOOP until conditions are met in PHP

Tags: php, api, for-loop

I have over a thousand data written in a text file and currently using remote upload API to import them to a Server. However, server can only handle 50 slots at a time.

Here's the script I made so far:

```
$txtfile = 'data.txt'; // this is the data (with over a thousand lines)

$fileData = function() {  // I made a function to read the text file LINE by LINE
    $file = fopen($txtfile, 'r');
    if (!$file)
        die('file does not exist or cannot be opened');
    while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
        yield $line;
    }
    fclose($file);
};


$server_slot = file_get_contents('https://someserver.com/api/current_slots/') //get remaining slot from the server

foreach ($fileData() as $line) { //process each line

    //import the data on that specific line
    $remote_upload_api = 'https://someserver.com/api/upload?data='.$line;
    $send_data = file_get_contents($remote_upload_api);

}
```

This script works so far but it sends all data to the server. Some process failed because slots are already full. Is it possible to TEMPORARILY stop the loop and check $server_slot overtime (probably another loop) until available slot is given then proceed to the loop again?

Im thinking of doing do-while statement but I find it hard to understand the right logic with my given situation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a while loop to check the server slot count, and then process the data in batches of 50.

```php
$txtfile = 'data.txt'; // this is the data (with over a thousand lines)

$fileData = function() {  // I made a function to read the text file LINE by LINE
    $file = fopen($txtfile, 'r');
    if (!$file)
        die('file does not exist or cannot be opened');
    while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
        yield $line;
    }
    fclose($file);
};


$server_slot = file_get_contents('https://someserver.com/api/current_slots/') //get remaining slot from the server
$data_batch = []; // array to store data in batches of 50

foreach ($fileData() as $line) { //process each line

    //import the data on that specific line
    $remote_upload_api = 'https://someserver.com/api/upload?data='.$line;

    // add data to batch
    $data_batch[] = $line;

    // if batch is full, process it
    if (count($data_batch) === 50) {
        // send data to server
        $send_data = file_get_contents($remote_upload_api);

        // check server response
        if ($send_data === 'success') {
            // reset batch
            $data_batch = [];
        } else {
            // check server slot count
            $server_slot = file_get_contents('https://someserver.com/api/current_slots/');

            // if slots are available, process batch again
            if ($server_slot > 0) {
                // send data to server
                $send_data = file_get_contents($remote_upload_api);

                // reset batch
                $data_batch = [];
            } else {
                // wait for slots to become available and check again
                sleep(60); // wait for 1 minute
            }
        }
    }
}
```